# C#: force constructor inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I've read a lot of questions of people asking how to have implicit ctor inheritance, so to not have to copy them around.

This question is totally the opposite: why C# is not forcing me to do it anymore? I want the derived classes to be forced to implement the base constructors...but it's not happening. What am I doing wrong?

**Base class**

```
public abstract class LogicalDevice
    {
        private LogicalDevice()
        {
        }

        protected LogicalDevice(string id)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Intermediate derived class**

```
public abstract class Device : LogicalDevice
    {
        public Device(string ID)
             : base("ID")
        {
        }

        public Device(ConfigurationData configuration)
             : base(configuration["ID"])
        {
        }
    }
```

**Final derived class**

```
internal class CoffeMachineDevice : Device
{
    public CoffeMachineDevice (ConfigurationData configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Why the class CoffeMachineDevice compiles?

Comment: "why C# is not forcing me to do it anymore" - it never has/does. The requirement is that every constructor in the derived class must (directly or indirectly) call *a* constructor in the base class but there's never been a requirement that there must be (at least one) constructor calling *each* constructor in the base.

Comment: If that is an answer, post it as such.

Comment: I am interested to learn why people believe completely false things about programming languages. Can you explain why you believe that C# ever had this restriction?

Comment: I'm also interested to learn why you want to *force a derived class to do something*. The purpose of a base class is to provide a *service* to implementers of derived classes, not to place requirements that they write code they don't want to. Can you explain what you are really trying to do here? There is probably a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: @EricLippert some basic misunderstanding, maybe? I mean, I never had a problem with C# and OOP, I've been programming in C# for 10 years in many different contexts, and everything was always fine. Those days I'm playing a bit with designs, "throwing code at the compiler" just to experiments things, I must have misunderstood something from the compiler error messages and then gone totally astray from there.

Comment: @EricLippert instead this "The purpose of a base class is to provide a service to implementers of derived classes, not to place requirements that they write code they don't want to"...well, unless someone removed "abstract" from OOP and C# while I was at the bathroom, sounds totally false.

Comment: @motoDrizzt: The *purpose* of abstract members is *not* to force a derived class to implement a method. The *purpose* of abstract members is either (1) to represent a portion of a workflow implemented in the abstract class that cannot be provided without knowledge of the derived class, or (2) as an easy way to use a base class as a contract rather than an interface. That an abstract method in effect requires work to be done in the derived class is a *consequence* of the design; it is absolutely not the *purpose* of the design!

Comment: @motoDrizzt: Consider for example a language in which there were no virtual methods, and hence no abstract methods. There is no *requirement* that an OO language have virtual methods, and some do not. In such a language would we say "hey, we haven't got virtual methods, but *we require some mechanism to force derived class authors to write code so let's invent a different mechanism to do that*?  Of course not. Forcing derived class authors to write code is not a desirable characteristic of an OO language.

Answer (score 1):

C# requires that every constructor in derived class must call a constructor in the base class. But there is no requirement that is must call each constructor of the base class.
That's why `CoffeMachineDevice` compiles.